# Show the number of months worked per year with employee start and end dates using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have employee start and end dates and I want to show the number of months worked per year using pandas.

```
ID | Start Date| End Date \
1  | 1\2016  | 3\2018  \
2  | 2\2017  | 4\2019 \
3  | 4\2019  | 3\2020
```

the general table I am looking for :

```
ID | Year | Months Worked \
1  | 2016 | 12 \
1  | 2017 | 12 \
1 | 2018  | 3\
2  | 2017 | 11 \
2  | 2018 | 12 \
2 | 2019  | 4\
3  | 2019 | 9 \
3  | 2020 | 3
```

Comment: Can you share the pandas code you used to get the first dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

First convert your datetime to a proper datetime object.

then we resample your dataframe into a daily level using some re-shaping.

then apply a groupby to count the unique months by year.

```
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'],format='%m\\%Y')
df['End Date']   = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'],format='%m\\%Y')

s = df.set_index('ID').stack().reset_index(name='date range')\
   .set_index('date range')\
   .groupby('ID',as_index=False).resample('M').ffill()\
   .reset_index(1)


final = s.assign(month=s['date range'].dt.month)\
         .groupby([s['date range'].dt.year,'ID'])['month'].nunique()\
         .reset_index(name='months worked')
```

---

```
print(final)

date range  ID   months worked
2016        1     12
2017        1     12
            2     11
2018        1      3
            2     12
2019        2      4
            3      9
2020        3      3
Name: month, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to datetime the two columns:

```
df["Start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Start Date"])
df["End Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])+ MonthEnd(1)
df.set_index("ID", inplace=True)
```

Get the number of months per year and per ID:

```
test = df.apply(lambda x: Counter(pd.date_range(x["Start Date"], x["End Date"], freq="M").strftime('%Y')), axis=1)

print(test)
ID
1    {'2016': 12, '2017': 12, '2018': 3}
2    {'2017': 11, '2018': 12, '2019': 4}
3                 {'2019': 9, '2020': 3}
```

Convert the Series to `dataframe` and get the final table:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame(list(test), index=df.index)
final_df["ID"]= final_df.index
pd.melt(final_df, id_vars="ID").dropna().sort_values("ID").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
ID  variable    value
0   1   2016    12.0
1   1   2017    12.0
2   1   2018    3.0
3   2   2017    11.0
4   2   2018    12.0
5   2   2019    4.0
6   3   2019    9.0
7   3   2020    3.0
```

Comment: @enchant339 let me know if this answer your question